# (very) beginner's example Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-process

Person X is on holidays for T weeks. At the end of each week, she gets a mosquito-bite, which infects her (for the following week) with a probability of 0.2. The state-space $Y_t$ is hence either I ("infected") or N ("no disease"). $Y_1$ is "N" - the person starts out healthy. No medication is available, so once infected the person is infected until the end of the holidays.

The tasks are now to (a) specify $P(Y_1)$ as well as $P(Y_t | Y_{t-1})$ for t = 2,3,...,T (b) to draw the transition diagram and (c) to determine the probability that person X is not infected in $Y_4$, i.e. in the fourth week.

My ideas and questions: (a)..? $P(Y_1)$ is obviously 1..? Am I missing something? For $P(Y_t | Y_{t-1})$ I would just specify the transition matrix P as follows (row 1 = infected, row 2 = not infected):

$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0.8 & 0.2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

**is there another way to specify** $P(Y_t | Y_{t-1})$? (b) The transition diagram contains two states, from the state "I" there is only an arrow to itself with probability 1, from the state "N" an arrow to itself with probability 0.8 and an arrow to "I" with probability 0.2. Regarding (c), I would calculate the respective entry in $P^3$, calculating first the respective entry in $P^2$ we get 0.2*0+0.8*0.8 = 0.64, and then $P(Y_4=N)$ = 0.64*0.8 = 0.512, the probability that X is not infected after 4 weeks of holidays.

**Are my solutions correct?** Thanks for your help!

Comment: (a) "$P(Y_1)$" makes no sense--perhaps you mean $P(Y_1=\text{N})$. (b) and (c) are not questions, so it seems you haven't actually asked anything.

Comment: "P(Y_1)" is what is written in the old exam sheets though...There are questions, for instance if there is another way to define the conditional probability in (a), and else I would like to know if my solutions in (b) and (c) are correct. Your comment seems unnecessarily sarcastic

Comment: @Pegah your clarification will increase the chances of getting a good answer, and it will also increase the productivity of people who do a lot of work helping others on this site.

Comment: What exactly was unclear? Serious question, so I can write better posts. I appreciate the help very much and so usually also try to put some effore into the formulation of my questions, but I find some charitability towards each other also important..my question seems reasonable to me, and the way I put it also clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know without a doubt that at time $t=1$ the person is not infected, so $P(Y_1 = N) = 1$. Maybe you are used to seeing a Markov chain start with an initial distribution that's not just a point mass at one value but a deterministic start is perfectly reasonable.

For the transition matrix, let $\Omega = \{I, N\}$ denote the set of possible values. You have one conditional distribution per value in $\Omega$, each distribution specifies $|\Omega|$ probabilities, and the distributions do not change over time, so you'll need to have $|\Omega|^2$ probabilities specified which is what is accomplished by your $2 \times 2$ transition matrix. So there's no way that does not involve specifying 4 probabilities. This matrix is unique up to relabeling of the states.

Finally, you need to compute $P(Y_4 = N)$. Here is how I would do it: you know that $Y_t = I \implies Y_k = I$ for all $k \geq t$ so the event $\{Y_t = N\}$ is equivalent to the event $\{Y_1 = N, \dots, Y_t = N\}$. This means
$$
P(Y_4 = N) = P(Y_1 = N, Y_2 = N, Y_3 = N, Y_4 = N) \\
= P(Y_4 = N | Y_3 = N)P(Y_3 = N | Y_2 = N)P(Y_2 = N | Y_1 = N)P(Y_1 = N) \\
= (0.8)^3 \times 1 = 0.512
$$
which agrees with your computation. You got the right answer but if I can avoid computing powers of matrices by hand I try to do so, and since we have $P(Y_t = N | Y_{t-1} = I) = 0$ the computations simplify to the point that we can get away with this more direct approach. But in total generality you would indeed need to compute powers of matrices.

Comment: Maybe the P(Y_1) is a typo in the old exam sheets, but we are not allowed to ask any questions about old exams...>_>..Anyway, perfect explanation, thank you so much!

Comment: @Pegah glad this was helpful! As long as you know exactly what it all means and can be rigorous if you'd like to be, I wouldn't worry too much about the $P(Y_t)$ notation. It is an abuse of notation but in my experience such abuses are pretty common